# Shorten Nested SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have made a database base to store answers according to nouns(mainkey) & verbs(subkey).

Tables:

```
questionkey: to store clauses/verbs
mainkey: to store nouns 
answer: to store answers (links answer to questionkey - one to many)
answerkey: links mainkey to answerid (many to many)
```

**I want to shorten/optimize my SQL query, currently i'm using this:**

```
SELECT answer FROM answer WHERE questionkeyid = 
(SELECT similarid FROM questionkey WHERE questionkeyword = 'define') 
AND answerid = 
    (SELECT answerid FROM answerkey WHERE answerkey.mainkeyid = 
        (select mainkeyid from mainkey where mainkeyword = 'chemistry'));
```

I'm new. & dont know how to apply joins if they could work

Original database:

```
CREATE TABLE mainkey (
  mainkeyid INTEGER  NOT NULL    ,
  mainkeyword VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL    ,
PRIMARY KEY(mainkeyid));
GO

CREATE TABLE questionkey (
  questionkeyid INTEGER  NOT NULL    ,
  similarID INTEGER  NOT NULL  ,
  questionkeyword VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL    ,
PRIMARY KEY(questionkeyid));
GO

CREATE TABLE answer (
  answerid INTEGER  NOT NULL    ,
  questionkeyid INTEGER  NOT NULL  ,
  Answer VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL  ,
  Views INTEGER      ,
PRIMARY KEY(answerid),
  FOREIGN KEY(questionkeyid)
    REFERENCES questionkey(questionkeyid));
GO

CREATE TABLE answerkey (
  mainkeyid INTEGER  NOT NULL    ,
  answerid INTEGER  NOT NULL  ,
PRIMARY KEY(answerid, mainkeyid),
  FOREIGN KEY(mainkeyid)
    REFERENCES mainkey(mainkeyid),
  FOREIGN KEY(answerid)
    REFERENCES answer(answerid));
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `JOIN`s.  This statement should do it for you:

```
SELECT a.answer 
FROM answer a
JOIN questionkey qk
  ON a.questionkey = qk.similarid
JOIN answerkey ak
  ON a.answerid    = ak.answerid
JOIN mainkey mk
  ON a.mainkeyid   = mk.mainkeyid
WHERE qk.questionkeyword = 'define'
  AND mk.mainkeyword     = 'chemistry'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got:

```
SELECT a.answer from answer a join questionkey q on a.questionkeyid=q.similarid join answer key ak on ak.answerid=a.answerid join main key m on m.mainkeyid=ak.mainkeyid
WHERE q.questionkeyword=‘define’ AND m.mainkeyword=‘chemistry’
```